# pertaining to my script, why i cant used where clause to the subquery counter = '1'

Tags: mysql, sql

I have question pertaining to my script, why i cant used where clause to the subquery ( where counter = '1')

I have one sample here please open the picture [image: sample screen to my script]

```
SELECT effectiveDate,


  (SELECT

  (CASE
    WHEN note='REGULAR LOGGED'
    THEN log
    WHEN description = description
    THEN description
  END)

  FROM timesheet WHERE counter ='1'

  ) as Counter1


FROM  schedules t1 LEFT JOIN timesheet t2 ON t1.empid = t2.empid AND t1.effectiveDate = t2.date
                   LEFT JOIN holidays t3 ON t1.effectiveDate = t3.date WHERE t1.empid ='40'
                   AND YEAR(t1.effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(t1.effectiveDate) = '1' GROUP BY t1.effectiveDate
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your picture is not a sample; it's just your query again, but in a screenshot.

Secondly, your answer is actually right there in the picture: the error message says that your subquery returns more than one row. Indeed, if you use a subquery in a select statement, that query should obviously return only one row.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

use **distinct** or **group by** the case statement.

Should look like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN .... END FROM TABLE WHERE
```

---

It's not recomended to use subquerys such as this, the cost of evaluating row by row at the select statement could get huge.

hint: Try improving your table structure.